# BuddyPress Toolbar

Tags: buddypress, admin-bar

Is there a way to call the toolbar or adminbar as you would a menu?

```
<?php 
    wp_nav_menu( 
        array( 
            'container' => false, 
            'menu_id' => 'nav', 
            'theme_location' => 'primary', 
            'fallback_cb' => 'bp_dtheme_main_nav' 
        ) 
    ); 
?>
```

I want to add the toolbar to a div within the header.php file. Currently the toolbar is being called in the footer.php and styled by the css to a fixed position in the body.

Or perhaps is there a script I could run which would amend a div around the `<div id="wp-admin-bar">`?

I am running the latest install of WordPress, 3.3.1 with BuddyPress as a plugin. Using a child-theme I created. I've noticed a few of the normal WordPress functions do not work well with the BuddyPress plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's actually an entire API for adding/removing items in the Toolbar.  You're specifically looking for the [`add_menu()` method](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu).

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to reply. I don't want to add anything to the menu, I just want to be able to place the admin bar inside a div so I can control where it is being placed on a page.

Comment: In that case, no. The toolbar is meant to be outside the regular styling/layout of your site and theme.